# vim feauture like in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, vim, ide, editor

is there a feature in vim like in Visual Studio editor, called with

```
    Alt + Shift + Arrow keys combination,
```

to edit text?

Comment: Not sure this is what you are looking for, but did you look at [VsVim](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/59ca71b3-a4a3-46ca-8fe1-0e90e3f79329)? "It integrates the familier key binding experience of Vim directly into Visual Studio's editor."

Comment: By the way - it would be much clearer if you actually explained what the `Alt + Shift + Arrow keys combination` actually does.

Comment: @Бахрам Ходжаев See this [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2010/11/20/vim-emulation-vstipedit0080.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need `blockwise Visual mode`

Activate it pressing `CONTROL-v` while in command mode, then use movement keys (h,j,k,l) to select a block. This is the most basic visual block mode interactive selection method.

Check the help on this topic from within vim using `:help visual-block`

More advanced selection methods can be used. An example is described in this [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/selecting-columns-with-visual-block-mode/)

Comment: Have you even read the question?

Comment: I did. I also looked for the functionality of the Alt-Shift-Arrow keys in Visual Studio, and apparently (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381730/what-is-the-command-for-block-select-in-visual-studio-2008) it serves the same purpose than visual block selection, am I wrong?

Comment: Bartek Banachewicz, yes, my english is bad

Answer (score 1):

See this stackoverflow question:

- [How to Select Columns in Editors (Atom,Notepad++, Kate, VIM, Sublime, Textpad,etc) and IDEs (NetBeans, IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, Visual Studio, etc)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802616/how-to-column-selection-in-editors-and-ides-notepad-kate-vim-sublime). It covers vim and pretty much every other IDE/editor and how to use "block wise selection" or "column selection".

As @dawud sugggested it's making use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> + arrow keys to select the columns in visual mode.