# Multiline editing in Visual Studio Code in Windows 11

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

Multiline editing in Visual Studio Code is not running in Windows. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow key</kbd> it will rotate my laptop screen.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381730/what-is-the-command-for-block-select-in-visual-studio-2008) and [here](https://www.visualstudiotipsandtricks.com/blog/2013/04/20/select-and-edit-vertical-blocks/)!

Comment: Works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>
2. Click on "Options and Support"
3. You can now either disable the hotkeys or change the keys.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Arrow</kbd> is famously captured by many graphics drivers, most notably Intel® Graphics Control Panel. It has nothing to do with Windows

Just open the display driver settings and disable those dumb hotkeys. After that you can use those shortcuts in other applications